# ISNULL not working correctly for money data type - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @V_FEE MONEY = 0.00
IF ISNULL(@V_FEE,'')=''
   SELECT 'FAIL'
ELSE
   SELECT 'PASS'
```

Why its returning 'FAIL' even my fee amount it 0.00. I am facing this issue in SQL Server.

Comment: why are you casting to char?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this happening because you are using a different type on isnull, you are passing a money type and you are using a varchar as default value. If you use same types on ISNULL you receive PASS answer on select.
Try this:

```
DECLARE @V_FEE MONEY = 0.00
IF ISNULL(@V_FEE, -1) = -1
      SELECT 'FAIL'
ELSE
     SELECT 'PASS'
```

Answer (score 2):

When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence.

Check it on [Data Type Precedence MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Because `''` converts to `0.0000` when converted to money.

```
select convert(money,'')
```

returns: `0.0000`

---

```
declare @v_fee money = 0.00
if @v_fee is null
   select 'fail'
else
   select 'pass'
```

returns: `pass`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @V_FEE MONEY = NULL

IF ISNULL(@V_FEE,0.00) = 0.00
   SELECT 'PASS'
ELSE
   SELECT 'FAIL'
```

In fact if you try:

```
DECLARE @V_FEE MONEY = 0.00;

SELECT ISNULL(@V_FEE, 'AAA');
```

It returns:

```
0.00
```